# How to insert multiple lines of highlighted text into Atom's platformio-ide-terminal?

Tags: atom-editor, platformio

I installed platformio-ide-terminal package in Atom. When I highlight and send multiple lines of text to my ipython terminal, it only runs the line where my cursor is blinking on.

Is there a way to send multiple lines of selected text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines are a complete statement, they must be separated by a semicolon. So you'd have to scroll back over the lines to insert a semicolon. If it is a single line that is too long to fit in a single terminal line, ipython should recognize this and generate '...' before the following lines as shown below.

[image]